# Events in Community Bulletin

Tags: support, community-bulletin, chat-event, community-events

At [Anime & Manga Stack Exchange](https://anime.stackexchange.com), we have scheduled an event on the chat. Does this appear on the Community Bulletin by itself, or do I need to add a community event on the site as well?

I ask this because the event did not appear on the bulletin until I created a Community Event. Was this redundant?

Also, do blog posts take priority over [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) meta posts and events in that particular site?

Comment: I doubt chat events will show up in the community bulletins. Reason being that anybody can make a chat room and add an event.

Comment: That was what I thought, but I did not know if it took some time to appear, or if it only appeared x time before the event takes place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They show up in the system message area (maybe on the bulletin as well, not sure), *while the chat event is running*.

[image: enter link description here]

Blog posts always show up there when new, as do [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts. Not sure what happens when you have too many such posts, my guess is that they are chronologically dropped off. Meta posts are basically used as "filler", to take up extra space not used by blog posts or  [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts.

Though Mystical is right, this has the potential for being abused. Not seen that happen, though :)